# How to refactor the if else code using typescript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i want to refactor the below ifelse code

below is my code,

```
const toggle = React.useCallback(
    async (itemId: string) => {
        if (isDrawing && editItemId === itemId) {
            cancelDrawing();
        } else if (isDrawing) {
            cancel();
            itemId && startDrawing(itemId);
        } else {
            itemId && startDrawing(itemId);
        }
    }
);
```

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you call `cancelDrawing` only when `isDrawing` is truthy?

```js
const toggleDrawing = React.useCallback(
    async (itemId: string | null) => {
        isDrawing && cancelDrawing();
        itemId && (editItemId !== itemId) && startDrawing(itemId);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isDrawing || editItemId === itemID) {
            cancelDrawing();
            itemId && startDrawing(itemId);
} else {
            itemId && startDrawing(itemId);
}
```